# Solving an equation representing pair of line yields two parallel lines but the original equation have a solution to it. Why?

Tags: geometry

Given equation for pair of straight line is
$$4x^2 + 4xy + y^2 -6x -3y -4=0$$

Solution given to me is that as following

If we shift origin for this equation this will become a homogenous equation. As we know angle between two line will remain same irrespective of origin chosen so let's assume we choose such an origin for which any term with degree not equal to 2 will vanish yielding
$$4x^2 + 4xy + y^2=0$$
which is $$(2x+y)^2=0$$
This will be equation for two individual lines in shifted origin so we bring are origin back  to original position which will give these equations an extra constants $$(2x+y+a)(2x+y+b)=0$$

comparing this to original equation
that is $$(2x+y+a)(2x+y+b)=0=4x^2 + 4xy + y^2 -6x -3y -4$$

solving this
$$4x^2 +y^2 +4xy +2x(a+b) +y(a+b) +ab=4x^2 + 4xy + y^2 -6x -3y -4$$

comparing coefficient of y $a+b=-3$ and constant $ab=-4$
solving yields $$a=1$$ and $$b=-4$$

This two lines $2x+y+1=0$ and $2x+y-4=0$ are certainly parallel which implies these two lines do not have any point of intersection

The why does point $(0,-1)$ satisfies $4x^2 + 4xy + y^2 -6x -3y -4=0$?

Is it solution for imaginary line? If yes please elaborate solution of lines yielded by above equation.

Also tell what's wrong with above method?
I can assure lines in result are correct because they can be also calculated lie this $$y= \frac{-(4x-3)±\sqrt{(4x-3)^2-4(4x^2-6x-4)}}{2}$$

Comment: The coordinates of every point on either line satisfy your equation. Point $(0,-1)$ is just one of them: a point on the first line. This has nothing to do with the intersection of the lines.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca solution of pair of line doesnot give point of intersection of two lines?

Comment: The solution of the SYSTEM of the two equations gives the intersection. Equation $A\cdot B=0$ is equivalent to $A=0\vee B=0$.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca got it

Comment: You can get rid of the linear terms by translating the origin, but there will still be a constant term.

Comment: @TedShifrin i'll once again verify solution with my teacher

Comment: Just to convince yourself: Compare $(x-y)^2=0$ and $(x-y)^2=1$.

Answer (score 1):

Though it would be convenient, "let's assume we choose such an origin for which any term with degree not equal to 2 will vanish" is not how it works. (Does it work starting from $x^2+y=0$?) One would need to make a literal substitution $u=x-a$, $v=y-b$ to see what the new equation is.

Comment: that's the exact solution i have been given i can solve it other way that is by using quadratic formula like this 
$$y= \frac{-(4x-3)±\sqrt{(4x-3)^2-4(4x^2-6x-4)}}{2}$$

yields
 $2x+y+1=0$ and
$2x+y-4=0$

Comment: Also $x^2+y$ is certainly not pair of straight lines.

Comment: @blueCat The solution you have been given is inconsistent. In the middle of the argument, when it comes to $(2x+y)^2=0$, it represents a pair of overlapping straight lines. Yet when it comes to $(2x+y+1)(2x+y-4)=0$, it represents 2 distinct parallel lines. So something must be wrong. Indeed if you follow Greg Martin's suggestion, you will find that you cannot reduce the equation to the form $(2x+y)^2$.